# When adding an element to a vector, how to know that a copy of the object is going to be made?

Tags: c++, object, reference, stdvector

I have an object called `LastQueryInfo lastQuery` in my class. Every time this object changes, I add it to a vector called `history`.

Initially, when I did `history.push_back(lastQuery)` I didn't know what would happen - is the vector going to make a copy of the object? or is it going to keep a reference to it? So if later I modify lastQuery, are all the objects (assuming they are references) in the history vector going to be modified?

After some testing, I found that `history.push_back(lastQuery)` is indeed going to make a copy of the object, then add it to the vector. But how can I know that without doing any tests? How can I know when C++ is going to make a copy, and when it's going to add the actual object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::vector` **always** stores a copy<sup>†</sup> of whatever you `push_back()`. So modifying the value you passed in will not affect the value stored in the vector. It isn't like Java or C# where an `Object o;` is actually a reference to the object, and the object lives until the garbage collector comes and picks it up when the last reference to it goes away. In C++, `Object o;` *is the actual object*, which will go away at the end of its scope.

So if `std::vector` only stores references to the objects you `push_back()`, then it will be utterly useless for things like this:

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
for(/* loop condition */) {
    int number = GetUserInput();
    numbers.push_back(n);
}
```

Since `number` will go away at the end of the loop, `numbers` would hold references to something that will not exist if `std::vector` was implemented by storing only references. If `std::vector` actually stored the values, you could access them even after the loop.

<sup>†</sup> C++11 supports [move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/can-someone-please-explain-move-semantics-to-me), so if the thing you're pushing back is actually a temporary that will go away soon, it'll *move* the internals of the object into the vector storage instead of copying. You can also explicitly use C++11's `std::move()` to "force" the move during `push_back()`. But vector will copy the value in every other case. It's an implementation detail to optimize the performance of vectors.

Answer (score 4):

Using `push_back` will always create a copy of the object that is being stored.

If you are using c++11, then there are two ways to avoid the copy :

- use the [emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace) method
- move the created object into the vector: `vec.push_back( std::move( obj ) );`

If you are not using c++11, then the only thing you can do is to use pointers or `boost::shared_ptr` as vector types.